# Run python code on html

Tags: html, python-2.7

I want to run python code in the box of ready html file 
how can I do that? 
this is my html file code .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Hello python!</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
      Output will be here 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a template engine like [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)?

Comment: You know , I need :  do something on json file then print out put on html then highlight words of sentences. Can I do this work with jinja  Or you have another suggestion?(I'm beginner in python )

Comment: try something, if you run into problems ask back with a  [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). otherwise you are not likely to get an answer...

Comment: I try and can print something like string in html but not exactly what I want. however thank you

Answer (score 1):

For my python, I use [trinket](http://trinket.io/). It works really well and it constantly updates. It is simple, easy to use and free. I would recommend it.

Hope it helps.